# Configuring Apache2 as a proxy for a sub directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, apache2

TLDR;

In development how do I tell reactjs that `app` is the home directory because I am getting the error

```
    GET http://myapp.local/static/js/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

when I make the request to

```
    http://myapp.local/app
```

I need it to find

```
http://myapp.local/app/static/js/bundle.js
```

Full Explanation

I have a development environment on my local machine running ubuntu 14.04 desktop that is running an apache server on port 80 and a react development server on port 3000.

I have a sub directory call app where I want to run my react web app. When in production this will just be a case of loading the static files from the build into that folder..

But in production I have a problem..

I have set up a reverse proxy with the web server so all requests to myapp.local/app go to localhost:3000

But now react is trying to find things in myapp.local instead of myapp.local/app

In a normal server I would set the document root to app, but not sure how to do this in react.

Also I have used create-react-app.

I hope I explained myself properly thanks in advance!